# Quickest way to get the key by value of a multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I have a structure as below. However there are 10,000 arrays under [data] and each array has about 100 keys

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Joe Bloggs
                    [1] => 01234
                    [2] => Manager
                    [3] => Male
                    [4] => 12
                )
             [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Claire Bloggs
                    [1] => 456
                    [2] => Manager
                    [3] => Male
                    [4] => 12
                )

             [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Mary Bloggs
                    [1] => 765756
                    [2] => Manager
                    [3] => Male
                    [4] => 12
                )
```

My question is given a string, how would I quickly search this array and bring back the key value of 0, as an example, where I search for the 2nd key with a value of 01234. I have 10,000 numbers to go through

Only way I can think of is to loop though and check i.e.

```
foreach ($array['data'] as $k=>$v) {
    if (if $v[1]=='01234') {
        // FOUND THE KEY which is 0
    }
}
```

Comment: And that's all. Add `break` if you need to find only one key.

Answer (score 2):

```
$key = array_search('01234', array_column($initialArray['data'], 1));
var_dump($initialArray['data'][$key]);
```

is most likely the fastest solution.
in worst case (where your searched element is the last element) on 10000 elements (my machine, your results may vary):

array_filter (worst time)
0.0418s

foreach (worst time)
0.0451s

array_search + reference (worst time):
0.0034s

so array_search seems to be the fastest (out of those 3 at least)

EDIT: added modified GIST here for you to check times yourself:
https://gist.github.com/janmyszkier/2974796128aa017aa9d4fd38465bede8